# Binding data to combobox in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, psql

I am trying to bind data to a combobox using c# and psql. However I can't get the combobox to update automatically when I add data to the database.

This is how I bind my combobox to the database:

```
private void bindProductComboBox(ComboBox box)
    {
        box.DataSource = allProducts;
        box.ValueMember = "product_id";
        box.DisplayMember = "name";
    }
```

allProducts is a private DataTable that receives all the Products in the database.

This is my ProductModel class

```
public class ProductsModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private DatabaseConnector db = new DatabaseConnector();
    private DbConnection conn = null;
    private Helper helper = new Helper();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String caller = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
        }
    }

    public void Add(String partCode, String name, Int16 supplier, Decimal unitCost)
    {
        using (this.conn = this.db.OpenConnection())
        {
            string statement = "INSERT INTO products ( part_code, name, supplier, unit_cost )" +
                               "VALUES ( @partCode, @name, @supplier, @unitCost )";
            DbCommand cmd = this.helper.initializeCommand(this.conn, statement);

            this.helper.createStringParam(cmd, "@partCode", partCode);
            this.helper.createStringParam(cmd, "@name", name);
            this.helper.createInt16Param(cmd, "@supplier", supplier);
            this.helper.createDecimalParam(cmd, "@unitCost", unitCost);

            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DataTable GetAll()
    {
        using (this.conn = this.db.OpenConnection())
        {
            String statement = "SELECT * FROM products";
            DbCommand cmd = this.helper.initializeCommand(this.conn, statement);

            cmd.Prepare();
            DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("product_id", typeof(Int16));
            table.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
            table.Load(reader);

            return table;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure I'm implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface correctly.

Comment: Raising the property changed event when you enter data to the database won't magically let the UI know that it should update the values. You might need to make another call to `GetAll()` and have the UI bind to those values.

Comment: Does this mean that I have to change the datasource every time I add to the database? That's what I'm doing now as a sort of band-aid solution but I was hoping there would be a better way to do it.